# According to firefox version changes, code written in selenium webdriver is not executing

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to drag and drop one element.But it is working fine in some version of Firefox  browser but for other version it is not working(Means drag and drop). I have not changed any code written in selenium web driver but still It is is behaving unexpectedly.

code sample:

```
if(dragElement.isDisplayed() && dropElement.isDisplayed())
{
    Actions action = new Actions(getWebDriver());   
    action.clickAndHold(dragElement);       
    action.moveToElement(dropElement).release().build().perform();
}
```

Comment: Which versions does it work in, and which does it not?

Comment: _behaving unexpectedly_  What exactly do you expect and what does it actually do? And what is your selenium version?

Comment: Behaving unexpectedly means, for some version of firefox browser It is dragging that element but suddenly the element is moving to its previous location.   selenium version::2.39.0